# Apache limit users per month to certain vhost

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx

Is there a way in apache to limit the amount of users that can view a site in a certain month? I'd need to do this for individual vhosts.

Something along the lines of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/website.com/public"
    **MONTHLY_USER_LIMIT** = 5000
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything in Apache that does this (or nginx) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see the point.  Are you worried about server strain? You could change the max concurrent tcp connections: `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn/` for concurrent connections and `proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog` for packet queue.

Comment: This depends heavily on how you define a "user". One connection? One Keep-Alive connection? One "page view"?

Comment: It would be one unique IP (I understand that this could be several users within an organization) - would this have to be done in code? Or is there any way of doing it with a webserver?

Comment: @tjameson - it's not a concern of server strain. It is to do with billing on a user/month basis.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could configure the access log to go to a program that does the counting and then turns off a site. You'd have to make it resilient to apache restarts.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite trivial if you're using something like PHP with Apache.  You could implement the count manually on a per user basis using cookies (optimally), or if they have cookies disabled use something clever.  This type of stuff belongs in a PHP script.

It seems that with a setup like yours, you probably have a user/password hash for authentication, so when they log in, log it. Every time they start a new session, log it.  If they reach 5000 sessions, return a 401 error or something explaining that they have exceeded their per-month allotment of views.

If this truly is on a per-user basis, a server-side script would make the most sense.  You don't even need to have a database, a simple text file will do the trick.

I'm pretty sure that a PHP script can access what host it is being accessed on (just look at the URL).